# How do I create EFI boot partition after it has been created by ubuntu installer in a system running Windows 8.1 pro

Tags: partitioning

I am trying to reinstall Ubuntu on my laptop that has Windows 8.1 pro installed on it already. It is asking me to create a separate partition for boot loader code. It is also asking me to go back to the partition menu and correct the error and that if I do not correct this error, boot loader installation will fail later. I already have a partition labelled: /dev/sda2 fat32 /boot/efi which is 104MB in size and 33MB has been used out of it. It labelled that as "Windows Boot Manager". Do I need to delete the OS Partition labelled Ubuntu 14.10 (14.10)? How do I complete the installation?|

Answer (score 0):

You need to correctly identify your [EFI System Partition (ESP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) and flag it as such in the installer. You do this in the dialog that asks for the filesystem type, IIRC. At one time, the Ubuntu installer called the ESP the "EFI boot partition," but I believe that name has been changed to "EFI System Partition" in the latest (development?) versions of the Ubuntu installer. Note that when you flag the partition in this way, you don't need to explicitly set the mount point to `/boot/efi`; the installer does that automatically.

It sounds like `/dev/sda2` is your ESP, and you've simply set it as a normal FAT partition mounted to `/boot/efi` rather than setting it as an ESP.

Answer (score -1):

First of all check the partitions in your windows 8.1. There should be unallocated space there available to install Ubuntu Linux. All the **empty logical partitions** won't be recognise by Ubuntu as  free spaces. There is a primary partitions available to make it as **Unallocated space**.

Let me know how many logical partitions and primary partitions available in your Laptop?

Comment: MuyisO almost certainly has an EFI-based computer with a GUID Partition Table (GPT). GPT doesn't support the concepts of primary, extended, and logical partitions.